# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't implement MPMediaPlayback protocol as advertised?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to use the MPMediaPlayback protocol's currentPlaybackRate() to slow down a video. I'm confused though as the class MPMoviePlayerController states that:

> You can control most aspects of playback programmatically using the methods and properties of the MPMediaPlayback protocol, to which this class conforms.

Except just above in the header here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html it doesn't seem to.

All I want to do is slow down the playback rate for a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That protocol is only available in iPhone OS 3.2 and later, which is currently only for iPad.

You should check the **Availability** section with a lot of the newer classes' methods since there are two platforms now.

Comment: Ah, it seems I had somehow added the older framework. Thanks for the answer!